# Динамическое изменение входных данных без перекомпиляции unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, файлы, unity3d-android

Пишу небольшую викторину на unity под android(вопрос и 4 ответа), возможно ли сделать так, что бы вопросы и ответы загружались из файла, в который можно было бы вносить изменения после компиляции проекта. Или же есть какой ни будь другой способ динамического добавления. Хочу что бы тесты можно было загружать без перекомпиляции

Comment: Использовать sql или json

Comment: Чтобы что-то загрузить, надо знать, откуда. Откуда вы зотите грузить данные?

Comment: Хочу грузить данные из файла(с текстовой информацией). Этими данными будут вопросы и ответы на тест, сделать я это хочу что бы ненужно было перекомпилировать проект под разные тесты, а просто можно было заменить вопросы-ответы в файле. (ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ МАБИЛЬНОЕ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использовать можно много чего под ваш запрос. Я бы посоветовал начать с чего-нибудь простого, допустим Json или CSV - таблица .  Вот вам [урок](https://youtu.be/mAeTRCT0qZg) собственно загрузки вопросов для некого NPC. Все что вам нужно, изменить строки под себя. А когда вы освоите импорт вот вам урок как загружать информацию из **[Google](https://leopotam.com/21/)** таблиц